# Python dict key with max value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with IP addresses and their free memory space.
I'm trying to save an IP to one variable and the next highest one to another variable.

```
masterdict: {'192.168.100.102': '1620', '192.168.100.103': '470', '192.168.100.101': '1615'} 

print masterdict

rmip = max(masterdict, key=masterdict.get)

print "<br>rmip<br>"
print rmip 

del masterdict [rmip]

print "<br>masterdict after deletion<br><br>"
print masterdict

nnip = max(masterdict, key=masterdict.get)

print "<br>nnip<br>"
print nnip
```

But the output i get is:

> masterdict
>   {'192.168.100.102': '1620', '192.168.100.103': '470', '192.168.100.101': '1615'}
>
> rmip
>   192.168.100.103
>
> masterdict after deletion
>   {'192.168.100.102': '1620', '192.168.100.101': '1615'}
>
> nnip
>   192.168.100.102

Why is it printing `192.168.100.103` as `rmip`? Shouldn't it be the one with the highest value? i.e. `192.168.100.102` and then `101` as `nnip`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values in your dictionary are strings so `max` is comparing them as strings.  If you want to compare them as integers, then you need to use the key function to convert the strings to integers...:

```
rmip = max(masterdict, key=lambda key: int(masterdict[key])
```

Or change the values to `int` and then use your current max statement:

```
masterdict = {k: int(v) for k, v in masterdict.items()}
rmip = max(masterdict, key=masterdict.get)
```

Comment: or change masterdict values to be ints and the current `max` function will work

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works great. 

@depperm Umm no. The dict is created this way. I'm taking the memory values from a bunch of VMs. And they're getting saved as strings. I'm not too sure how to change that.